# Why the output does not show correctly?

Tags: scala

Typing the following statement in the bash:

```
    developer@playground:~$ echo dump | nc localhost 32773 | grep brokers
```

I've got:

```
    /brokers/ids/1
```

But in the scala console, I did not get any result:

```
    scala> "echo dump | nc localhost 32773 | grep brokers".!
    dump | nc localhost 32773 | grep brokers
    res2: Int = 0
```

I also tried:

```
scala> "echo dump | nc localhost 32773 | grep brokers".!!
res0: String =
"dump | nc localhost 32773 | grep brokers
"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe `|` is interpreted by the shell, but you're not invoking the shell.

Try the `ProcessBuilder`'s pipe command.

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "echo | wc".!
| wc                       <--- not what we want
res0: Int = 0

scala> ("echo" #| "wc").!
      1       0       1
res1: Int = 0
```

Or, invoke the shell.

```
scala> Seq("sh", "-c", "echo | wc").!
      1       0       1
res2: Int = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `import sys.process._` and then execute the command `"echo dump | nc localhost 32773 | grep brokers".!` :

```
scala> import sys.process._
scala> "echo dump | nc localhost 32773 | grep brokers".!
```